# Ledger Nano S - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, udev, dmesg

I need help getting my Ledger to connect. Currently I am ***stuck on the verify screen.***

I am running *Ubuntu 20.04* and *Ledger Live Desktop 2.33.1-linux-x86_64*

I have ran the troubleshooting steps here: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165269-Fix-USB-connection-issues-with-Ledger-Live?support=true

I have also ran `dmesg` and I get this error.[image]

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has it ever worked after you installed Ledger? Seg fault is often a faulty program or bad ram.

Comment: No this is the first time I'm running it.

Comment: Can you remove it and see if that fixes it?